# Can I change the extension from .HTML to .phtml?

Tags: magento2, module, payment, phtml, html

I've got a custom payment module. I've `.HTML` checkout button page in this path.

```
\app\code\vendorName\moduleName\view\frontend\web\template\payment\vendor.html
```

Can i change `.phtml instead of .HTML`

Comment: Explain your requirement, we can do our logic in html using ko js.

Comment: I need the API keys from the payment method in the JS.

Answer (score 2):

No that will not work unless you rebuild the checkout to not use UI components, this is because UI component templates are rendered client side which does not support PHP as it runs on the server and not the client.